# Will TensorFlow use multiple GPU's by default?

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I do not allocate the device using "with tf.device(d):", will TensorFlow use only one GPU or will it use all the available GPUs when one GPU is not enough?

Answer (score 2):

The [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu) says:

> If you have more than one GPU in your system, the GPU with the lowest ID will be selected by default. If you would like to run on a different GPU, you will need to specify the preference explicitly.